# Attempt to read from field on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview

So I'm making this app which saves data onto the sdcard, reads the data, and puts it into a ListView. I'm having two issues. One, the list view is not updating everytime I add a new file, unless I press back and re open the app. Two, when I kill the app from the recents menu, and then open it, I get a Null pointer exception as stated in the title. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm a complete beginner at this. So please bear with me

Here's the logcat :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.bluetooth.infoshare.infoPerson.firstName' on a null object reference
>               at com.bluetooth.infoshare.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:63)

Comment: Add some code, and clarify the question.

Comment: For problem #1, you likely just need to run yourListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after a file gets added to the SD card. For problem #2, you need to post your code.

Comment: I have my code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805570/attempt-to-read-from-field-java-lang-string-com-bluetooth-infoshare-infoperson)

Comment: Please post your logcat trace when it crashes and relevant code block.

Comment: Updated post with logcat. Link is in my above comment. Thanks

Comment: Problem 2 is most likely caused by not implementing the activity life cycle correctly.

Comment: @Henry can you please explain more? I'm new to this. :)

Comment: @SudarshanSunder Failure to correctly save and restore the activity state could lead to the problem. See the docu for details http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

for problem #2, maybe you not implementing the activity life cycle

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
protected void onStart();
protected void onRestart();
protected void onResume();
protected void onPause();
protected void onStop();
protected void onDestroy();
```

This may help : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html